# How may I create a continuously looping animation?

Tags: animation

I would like to create a continuously looping animation that repeats itself constantly and without my help (I do not want to create one animation and then copy and paste it over and over again).  A good example would be the rotational movement of a helicopter's blades.  I am not repulsed by a scripting solution, and would indeed welcome it.  How may I accomplish this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to add a *Cyclic F-modifier*. Go into the Graph Editor and select the keyframes that you wish to loop over (over their respective time period), press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>, and select "Make Cyclic (F-modifier)".

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to limit the number of loops? For example, what if I want it to be repeated only three times?

Answer (score 25):

You can do this by adding a *Cycle F-modifier* to the desired **F-Curve**. After adding the modifier, if you want it to have continuous motion, and not simply start over each time, you'll need to set **Repeat with offset**.

[image: F-Curve modifier]
[image: Repeat with offset]

Answer (score 24):

You can use the NLA editor to make a repeating animation.[image]

Changing the repeat value will change how many times the animation will repeat. Just make sure your animation was converted to an NLA strip otherwise you won't be able to repeat the track.

Comment: So how to you " Just make sure your animation was converted to an NLA"

Comment: This is by far the best and easiest answer. Messing around with the graph editor is a pain.

Comment: Upvoted because the NLA is far more powerful and flexible for this purpose. The Cyclic Modifier is only really useful if the object repeats the animation throughout the scene.