# How to spin more than one propellers(objects) at the same time

Tags: animation

I was making a drone animation and i wanted to know how i can make the three propellers i made to rotate like a helicopter does at the same time in an animation.

Answer (score 1):

**[Using Drivers.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/it/dev/animation/drivers/index.html)**

Similarly to my [answer here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38963/15543) I believe drivers are a great way to animate mechanical objects.

For a very simple case the rotation axis, in this case z, can be "spun" by setting the rotation to the frame, by typing `frame` (known to drivers, as the current frame) into the field.

[image]

[image]

Adding other variables as custom properties on the parent empty, eg on / off / speed, as well as on the individual rotor empties themselves, could change the speed of each.

Answer (score 0):

Create a cube.
Name it something like Rotator.
Move it to some other layer.
 
Now in Properties windows, select your propellers & add "Copy Rotation" constraint.
IN "Copy Rotation" -> target , select the Cube Rotator.
Animate your Rotator and it will in turn, rotate your propellers.
[image: Cube handling Rotation of Other Cubes]
[image: Constraint Option]