# How to make a cycled cloth simulation?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I want to make a slowly waving(?) flag, but it must be a loop, and i don't know how to do it :( Help me please

P.S. Also interested in making more realistic material with cycles, but that's not necessary

Comment: here you find a tutorial, just in case
http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-an-animated-flag/

in the comments someone suggested, in order to make a loop, to add the same animation - reversed - at the end...

Comment: also see other answers here about looping animations, like http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/440/how-may-i-create-a-continuously-looping-animation.

it is perhaps better, in order to learn, separate the steps: model the flag/cloth/materials, then animations/loop cycles