# How would I animate vertices randomly up and down (+looping)

Tags: modeling, animation

I've got a plane which is displaced by a voronoi texture like this.[image]

And know I want to give each vertex a looping animation where the vertex slides up and down on his Z-axis (looping). I want each vertex to have a random animation offset. What's my approach? Python scripting?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it, the simplest I can come up is to set an empty as object in the displace modifier, animate the empty and make the first and last frame the same, then [make "cyclic" extrapolation of the animation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/440/how-may-i-create-a-continuously-looping-animation) 
If you need add randomness, you can consider [the noise f-curve modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fmodifiers.html)

First example with 3 keyframes and the noise modifier

[image]

The second example use Make Cyclic f-modifier and only two keyframe

[image]

**Not sure why in the second example the loop works only twice** if someone knows please advice, either it's a bug or it's a matter of mapping (I'm to tired now to debug)
[image: example cyclic noise using keyframe]

Comment: discard the double frame in the animated  gif it is cyclic!

Comment: If you wish to add more of a random effect, animate your empty in a circular motion, and rotate/scale it about it own axis during that loop to add more variation. The only thing lacking in this example is that it looks like a fast-forward/rewind loop where the circular animation would solve the rewind effect. just make sure that it starts and stops in the same Location/Rotation/Scale and Cyclic works very well. I will post a supporting answer w/ a supporting Blend.

Comment: I'm using a voronoi texture instead of a noise texture but when I animate my empty the interpolation of the vertices is very jagged and not smooth like yours.

Comment: note that I've use a subdivision surface after the displacement. Play also with the strength and ramp color values

Answer (score 2):

**Please don't mark this as the answer - If this helped you, please give diramazioni the credit, and please see my comment as to what is going on here as a response to his post.**

This is just to support his initial concept.

[image]

[image]

Comment: @RickRIggs instead of creating a new answer consider editing existing ones. It's OK to edit if you feel you can enhance someone else's post.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is apply the displace modifier, then hook each vertex to an empty and use a Noise f-curve modifier to displace each empty by a random amount.  With a lot of vertices that would take a lot of setting up so maybe someone has a more automatic approach as a solution.

[image]

Comment: that's what the object option it's for in the displace modifier, no need to use a hook for each vertex, one empty will do the trick

Comment: I think OP wants each vertex to have its own random movement.  How would that work with your method?

Comment: see the example provided below

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Animation Nodes. You have to copy that mesh to a new object, and iterate trought the different vertex adding the result of a vector wiggle, with a different seed according to the index of each vertex.

Comment: Can you provide a working example?