# Loop multiple objects along the same path

Tags: animation

What I want to do is to have multiple identical cubes all following the same (non-circular) path, each with a different starting offset. And when one cube reaches the end, it teleports back to the start and continues along that path again. I want to do this without having to manually animate everything.

I tried to do what they suggested here: [How may I create a continuously looping animation?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/440/how-may-i-create-a-continuously-looping-animation) by animating the evaluation time on the path and making that cyclic, but that doesn't seem to work for multiple objects.

What I want to happen (using multiple paths to do this, want to use a single path): 
[image: What I want to happen]

What happens when I use a single path and set the offset values on the cubes:
[image: What happens when I use a single path]

Comment: It's never easy to help people with "that doesn't seem to work". Please explain exactly what doesn't work, or better [upload your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/).

Comment: The animations in your question have text that is excessively small.  Please include screen shots so helpers can read the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Drivers and Follow Path constraint.**

Drive the offset of the constraint from 0 to 1 using Fixed Position.

Hard coded 250 as the path length in frames. The driver method has two parameters, the current frame (`scene.frame_current` is known to the driver namespace as `frame`) and the offset at frame 0.

```
import bpy

path_length = 250 # path length in frames

def offset(frame, start=0):
    # start position at frame 1
    f = round(frame + start * path_length)
    return (f % path_length) / path_length

bpy.app.driver_namespace["offset"] = offset
```

Sample file and image with Cube (offset 0), Cube.001 (0.2) and Cube.002 (0.4).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seems to work pretty nicely so far, though I would like to see if there's a solution without the need for any scripting. I'll accept the answer tomorrow if nothing else comes up.