# Stopping Follow Path at the beginning

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, keyframes, path, nla-editor

I'm mixing animations in NLA editor, and I want start with follow constraint turned off.

For example, I want my character to wave, and then play the walk cycle with follow path.

The keyframing influence didn't help, the timeline is snapping origin forward.

Comment: Suggest with follow path constraint, removing path animation and keying in the offset (0 is one end 1 is the other) [Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/89181/15543)  This way the animation can be moved easily using NLA.

Answer (score 1):

Okey I found the solution to keyframe follow path curve. You Need Delete Evalution Time in Fcurve.[image]

And Then Manually Set Values Frames and Evalution Time, Click I to keyframe.[image]