# Where can I see and edit keyframes for texture properties?

Tags: animation, materials, transparency, keyframes

I am pretty new to blender and I want to animate the alpha value of a texture. (Actually I want to have an object appear and disappear in a pulsating way). I need to do it in eevee, NOT in cycles.

I have succeeded to change the opacity of an object by changing the alpha value of the texture:
[image]

And then switching to «alpha blend» within the textures settings:
[image]

So far so good.
Now I would want to create a pulsating animation between alpha 0.25 and 0.75. I found [this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/440/how-may-i-create-a-continuously-looping-animation) where it's said that I could create my animation with keyframes and then add a cyclic f-modifier.

The problem is, that I can't see my keyframes I am setting for the texture.
I can open up my timeline, go the desired frame and right-click on the alpha property:

[image]

This will indeed add a keyframe, and I can see that the texture is changing over time, but they keyframes don't show up in any view.

I tried to change to «Graph Editor» and deselected the «only selected»
[image]

But I can nowhere find the keyframes for my alpha property!

I would be super happy to know where I can edit them in a timeline-like way and how I can then add a cyclic f-modifier to that animation, changing between the values of 0.25 and 0.75.

Thank you for any help.

PS: I am using blender 2.81

Answer (score 4):

I needed to deselect *Selected Only* from the *Curve Editor* header and use the search bar or enter all the nested properties of the material.

The material had to be selected within the project panel where you see all your object hierarchy.

After that I could add keyframes, and use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> to add a *Cycle F-Curve modifier*.

[image]